# How to reset password in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my layout page found below cases:

resetpassword.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
<div id="profileTeacher" type="view" class="demo-section k-header">
@include('layouts.common.flash-message')

   {!! Form::open(['url' => 'updatepassword',  'method' => 'post'])  !!} 
<form id="profileTeacherForm" method="post" action="" >
    <ul id="fieldlist" >
            <li>
            <label style="color:Green;font-size:15px">Update Password</label>
            </li> 
            <li>
             <table id="lessonPlanTable">

                 <tr>
                  <td><label> Current Password  </label> </td>
                  <td><input type="password" id="curr_password" name="curr_password"  class="k-textbox"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td><label> New Password </label> </td>
                  <td><input  type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password" class="k-textbox"/></td>
                  </tr>

                 <!--tr>
                  <td><label> Confirm Password </label> </td>
                  <td><input type="password" id="confm_password" name="confm_password"  class="k-textbox"/  ></td>
                  </tr-->
                  </table>
                </li>
        <li><br>
            <button id="updateTeacherProfile" class="k-button k-primary" 
type="submit">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </li>
        <br><br>

    </ul>
 </form>

 </div>
 @stop
```

StudentController.php

```
 public function UpdatePassword(Request $request)
{
    $curr_password = $request->curr_password;
    $new_password  = $request->new_password;


if(!Hash::check($curr_password,Auth::user()->password)){
echo 'The specified password does not match';
}
else{
    $request->user()->fill(['password' => Hash::make($new_password)])->save;
    echo 'Updated Successfully';

 }
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('/studentresetpassword', function () {
return view('layouts.student.resetpassword');
});


Route::post('/updatepassword ', 'Student\StudentController@UpdatePassword');
```

No such error in this file. All the process are done without getting any error.When i put current password as wrong it also gives the echo message as good also gives an echo message "Updated Successfully" when i put current and new password..but in a table level updation cannot be done..please provide me a solution.

Comment: @Nisanth are u here

Comment: as per last change display module name ?

Comment: this is the result for last one:......Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
)

Comment: Please remove print_r() from show function and check your view page

Comment: And i also remove from show() and please check

Comment: nothing display its a blank white page only shows..

Comment: please create new question

Comment: sir actually sorry 3 days leave here so incompletion leads to danger so we will start as freshly minded on monday

Comment: @Nisanth sure and can you accept my last my answer?

Comment: @Nisanth If it is possible for you

Comment: ya your answer and way of treating are also very well sir we will discuss on monday

Comment: @Nisanth Ok bye

Comment: @Nisanth so accept and upvote to my last answer

Comment: hi @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `StudentController.php` should look like:

```
public function UpdatePassword(Request $request)
{
    $curr_password = $request->curr_password;
    $new_password  = $request->new_password;


if(!Hash::check($curr_password,Auth::user()->password)){
echo 'The specified password does not match';
}
else{
    $request->user()->fill(['password' => Hash::make($new_password)])->save();
    echo 'Updated Successfully';

 }
```

Comment: It works Thanks  AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd..this is the 2nd time i got a solution from u.. thanks a lot..

Comment: @Nishanth Glad to help and if my answer is your solution then please upvote to my answer

Comment: 15 Reputations are needed to upvote i have only 7..so I cant do sry..definitely I will do  in future after getting a minimal reputations

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd oh, it was hard to see :)

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd how can i check the the new and confirm password are matches..please give an idea to use within a if condition..actually confirm password is the another extra field set added recently.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function resetPassword(Request $request)
{

    if (!Hash::check(Input::get('currentPassword'), \Auth::user()->password)) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['currentPassword' => 'Incorrect password']);
    }

    $this->validate($request, [
        //'currentPassword' => 'required|min:6',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    $input = \Input::all();

    $user = \Auth::user();
    $user->password = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $user->save();        

    Session::flash('flash_suceess_message', 'Your password reset successfully!');
    return redirect('/home');
}
```